# Does anybody know this plant's Latin name?

Tags: identification, herbs

[image]

As far as I know, this plant belongs to a temperate herbaceous species, it lives outdoors in the Netherlands. Does anybody know its Latin name?

Comment: Bit more info would be good - for one thing, is this a picture of a climber against a wall, or a close up of it coming out of the ground, and second, any other info, like what type of flower, when and the colour. Eventual height, maybe?

Comment: Does it grow a flower stock in the summer? It looks like sorrel (rumex acetosa), but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Bamboo Thanks for the reply. I didn't see its flowers, but I heard this plant has red flowers, which bloom in summer. The approximate height is 40 cm (without flowers). This picture is a close up of it coming out of the ground. Thanks.

Comment: @michelle Thanks for the answer. Yes, I heard that this plant blooms red in summer.

Comment: Might well be the one Michelle suggested, but its pretty hard to be sure when its at this stage.

Comment: See http://www.dep.state.fl.us/water/wetlands/delineation/docs/fl_wetland_plants_key/herb_dicot_key.pdf

Comment: Does this look at all similar? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex#mediaviewer/File:Rumex-obtusifolius-foliage.JPG

Answer (score 3):

Following up with michelle's comment, it definitely appears to be in the rumex genus.  Take a look at some of the different species.  I followed stormy's link to wikipedia.  Here's another, although the stem is redder: [*Rumex obtusifolius*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex_obtusifolius)